# UIImageVIew in TableCell shows not the correct SIze

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder

i have some strange Problem. I use the Interface Builder to create a Custom TableCell with three Labels and one UIImageView:

[image]

I want that the Cell has a little space to the TableView (the blue border), so i put an extra View inside the Cell. As you can see the UIImageVIew is realy small and not higher than two labels, but when i run my code on the device the UIImageView is high as the white View and even covers the Label a little bit. The only thing i do in my Code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CustomCellReuseID";

GTEventCustomCell *eventCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
if (eventCell == nil) {
    eventCell = [[GTEventCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
}

// Configure the cell...
[eventCell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"]];
.
.
.
```

What´s wrong?

Comment: ImageView gets frame from heart.png size? Try to set eventCell.imageView.frame after you assign image or change imageView settings to scale to fill

Comment: as @OlegFedorov said try with modeScale , you can even use cliptoBounds=yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will **fix your problem**:

```
eventCell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have not missed the auto layout constraints for the objects inside the custom cell.

If not select a label/view
 in toolbar Editor > Resolve Auto Layout issues > add missing constraints

and change the auto layout constraint as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I just think you should change your properties in the right panel.

You can also desactivate autolayout constraints and, to be sur to place your items at the good place, set them programmatically.

example :
at the top of your file :

```
#define X_Cell_Padding 10
#define Y_Cell_Padding 10
```

in cellForRow methods :

```
 [[cell yourImageView] setFrame : CGRectMake(X_Cell_Padding, Y_Cell_Padding, yourImageView.frame.size.width, yourImageView.frame.size.height)];
```

don't forget to create a custom cell class with your IBOutlet yourImageView and to set this class for the cell in your storyboard / xib